# Set panoramaItem Orientation via code in WP7

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I have added the images dynamtically from a url to panorama item. I need the width to be 800 which the image should be in the next item space also. For that in my previous application I have set the orientation to horizontal in Xaml. But no i need to set in code but i cant is there any way to do that.

```
private void AddItem(string uri, string header)
    {
        var panoramaItem = new PanoramaItem();
        panoramaItem.Width = 800;
        panoramaItem.Height = 550;

        panoramaItem.Header = "";
        var grid = new Grid();

        var image = new Image();

        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        panoramaItem.Content = image;
        pan.Items.Add(panoramaItem);
    }
```

Comment: `panoramaItem.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal` doesn't work or ?

Comment: when i enter  panoramaItem.Orientation = Orientation. ,then in the intellisense i didnt see the option for horizontal and vertical only compareto,equals,to string like that.May i know whats the reason

Comment: use `System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal`

Comment: I have only system.windows.controls.common or primitives..

Comment: Add reference to `System.Windows` assembly

Comment: Sorry now i have added that in my code like panoramaItem.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal; it works fine Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PanoramaItem` has an `Orientation` property for handling scrolling direction. It takes value of `System.Windows.Controls.Orientation` enum in `System.Windows` assembly. Your code should looks like:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
```

And orientation assigment:

```
panoramaItem.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
```

Comment: In the above code i set the orienation to horizontal.now the first panorama item appears in some distance that it seems like the second item.the first item space is empty when i flip horizontally the first iamge appears like a second item.i.e the first image starts at half of the panorama control title MY APPLICATION. Instead of starting under the letter M the first panorama item starts at PPL.

Comment: Very hard to understand what you see. Perhaps, this helps you: default `Image` `Stretch` method is `Uniform`. So, if your images is not a 800x550 you will see some blank areas.  But, this is another question...